# C Macros for more complex functions

Tags: c, macros

I've seen simple examples of macros, but wondering about something more complex, say with if statements and reassigning given variables. Can more complex expressions like this be done in a macro? I've got a function that'll be run billions of times, so it would nice to have the preprocessor just throw the code in there rather than passing variables back and forth.

Say I have the following function:

```
int foo(int a, int b, int c){  
if (a > 2)  
  c = a;  
if (b > 3)  
  c = b;  

return a + b + c;  
}
```

How can I make this into a macro?

Comment: Umm. What exactly are you trying to do? Why will making this a macro change anything.

Comment: There is no reason to use macros for this these days - if calling overhead is significant then use inline functions but macros have not been needed since C89 and have numerous shortcomings and pitfalls.

Comment: @Paul: Macros are the only way to do generic programming in C. What if OP wanted a function like that which works on `int`, `long`, and `double` arguments (in any combination)?

Comment: @R..: then OP should have mentioned that in the question ;-p The "this" in "for this" isn't "generic programming" as far as I can see.

Comment: I agree macros are useless here. I guess I missed the "for this" in Paul's comment.

Comment: @R: Good point re generic programming, although I'd argue that this is a kluge. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Note that macros aren't the same as function calls - macros actually replace the C source code where they are used instead of calling and returning - so there can be a lot of unexpected behavior!  Your example could be made into a macro like so:

```
#define FOO(a,b,c)((a)+(b)+(((b)>3)?(b):((a)>2)?(a):(c)))
```

But again, there are [many pitfalls when using complex macros](http://www.brainbell.com/tutors/c/Advice_and_Warnings_for_C/Macros_and_Miscellaneous_Pitfalls.html), such as unclear operator precedence and duplicated auto-increment/decrement operators.

It's probably best to heed the advice of other answers and use alternative strategies than complex macros.

Comment: @Alexandre: maybe you could post an answer explaining why answering his question as it is asked is a bad idea?

Comment: Why the downvote? It looks correct to me. Dangerous or not, he answered the question.

Comment: @maerics: The arguments are evaluated multiple times (so if you pass in `x++` for `a`, then `x` gets incremented 3 times and you have undefined behavior), and it fails to detect incorrect parameter types being passed, to name 2 reasons.

Comment: @maerics: there are numerous problems with the macro you have defined above, e.g you have not even put parentheses around a, b and c, so it will fail in spectacular ways if any of these are expressions. Not to mention side effects, multiple evaluation, etc.

Comment: @Adam, Paul: agreed, updated the answer to mention this but per Dave's comment, the question is "how would I make this function a macro", no?

Comment: @Dave: there are zillions of "macros are evil" faq on the internet which will do this better than me. I don't like to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I agree. I googled "macros are evil", and got 12900 hits. But then I googled "Just answer the question", and got over 4 million. :) But seriously, I agree with you all that it's a bad idea, it was just a harsh downvote.

Comment: Agree with @Dave, we are not here to mollycoddle people.  By all means explain why doing this is usually a bad idea, but don't pretend that the technically correct answer to the question does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Easy - don't use macros - just use inline functions:

```
__inline int foo(int a, int b, int c)
{  
    if (a > 2)  
        c = a;  
    if (b > 3)  
        c = b;  
    return a + b + c;  
}
```

Comment: Or use `inline` instead of `__inline` if you have a serious C compiler. Not that actually marking the function `inline` has much effect on whether it is inlined by a decent compiler, but the fact that definitions of inline functions are present in the TU containing the call does.

Comment: @Steve: indeed, __inline is safer and more portable for C code but most modern/decent compilers will recognise inline, although it may require a command line switch for this to be enabled.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "portable". If a given compiler doesn't support `inline`, then who knows what other parts of the current C standard it fails to support? If you want to write code that's portable back to C89, then you cannot rely on any facility for inline functions, and the best bet is usually to define a MY_STATIC_INLINE macro which will be defined to `static inline` in C99, `static` in pure C89, and some compiler-specific thing involving `__inline` where available.

Comment: `__inline` is completely unsafe; its use has undefined behavior since the name is reserved for the implementation. `inline` is safe, because if your compiler is pre-C99, you can simply `#define inline` to omit it, or `#define inline __inline` to use some compiler-specific `__inline` keyword.

Comment: @R: inline is not completely safe in pre C99 code - you can't simply #define it away as there may be existing functions, variables, etc in the code named inline.

Comment: @Anonymous down voter - please at least have the courtesy to explain why you think this is a bad or unhelpful answer.

Comment: @Paul: You're the one writing the code, so don't use `inline` except as a keyword (and fix any such problems in existing code; it's a simple search-and-replace). It's perfectly safe from the *compiler* not messing it up. In C, nothing is safe from incompetent programmers messing it up. :-)

Comment: @R: not always so simple when dealing with legacy code, third party libraries, which is of course the motivation for introducing __inline, __asm, et al with double underscore prefixes so as to avoid naming clashes.

Comment: __inline is not at all portable. In the world of PC programming most compilers follow C99, but in the big world outside the desktop, C90 still rules, and people even intentionally avoid C99. Some C90 compilers have a good portable way to inline, however, through #pragma INLINE or similar. That is the most portable way, in C90.

Comment: @Lundin: I'm not so sure about PCs and C99, or at least Windows PCs - Visual Studio *still* doesn't support C99 (although it does support __inline). Of course you can safely #ifdef away __inline if a given compiler does not support it.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you could replace your function with a macro, in all likelihood, it will make no difference to the performance.  Any reasonable compiler will have moved the function inline if it it thinks it will help.

Answer (score 1):

If it looks like it should be a function, then make it a function.

Compiler technology has become good enough over time, so you don't have to worry about stuff like this. Have trust in your compiler and you should be fine.